# How can I delete a "Run Script" build phase in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I've added a script to the build phases of my project, and I no longer want it–how can I delete it? Other answers I've seen on Stack Overflow seem to be for older versions of Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope this helps. You can add and remove the script from the same page itself.

[image]

Comment: Oh how obvious! I don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click the little `x` button to the right of the title of the phase you wish to delete.

Answer `Delete` to the subsequent "Are you sure?" dialog.